# can't read user initialized as null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I am new to React and web programming. It was working all ok until I went into inspect and deleted the user from local storage to check if everything is working fine. But once I did that and there is no user in local storage the login page isn't showing up. what is going wrong here. the initial user state is set to null is what is throwing me off

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')
    Module.<anonymous>
    D:/Web Applications/React/Ecommerce/Shop/admin/src/requestMethods.js:5
      2 | 
      3 | const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";
      4 | 
    > 5 | const TOKEN = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).user).currentUser.accessToken;
      6 | 
      7 | 
      8 | export const publicRequest = axios.create({
```

**and here is my requestMethods.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";

const TOKEN = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).user).currentUser.accessToken;


export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

**My userReducer.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    currentUser: null,
    isFetching: false,
    error: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    loginStart: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
    },
    loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.currentUser = action.payload;
    },
    loginFailure: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.currentUser = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Please remove the java tag

Answer (score 0):

Because if `presist:root` if not exist in the localStorage, it will be null, and you can't get `user` property from `null`, you need conditionally check if the value exist.

```js
const root = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))

const user = root?.user

let TOKEN = user?.currentUser.accessToken;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i followd your solution but now i get the same can't read null error for the isAdmin line does  it also need to be conditioined?                                                                const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser.isAdmin);

Comment: You are welcome, Yes, it should be the same.